# Custom line styles for a given range

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I'm trying to highlight a portion of a scatter/line plot, but using separate plots for each highlight and get them overlaid on top of the original plot is not working for me because the original plot is doing cubic curve smoothing and I need more points in the highlight than required for the curve to fit the one in the back.

I haven't found any delegate/data source way of specifying a line style for a given range in the documentation. Is there a way of achieving this?

If not possible, is my approach of multiple plots the way to go or is there something else you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to specify different line styles for separate data ranges. Your solution of multiple plots is the right one, although as you discovered, it won't work with smoothed lines.

You could do the smoothing yourself by turning off the curved line interpolation and adding additional plot points between the known data points. Then you would know where to separate the data for the individual plots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Is there any way of extracting the precise coordinates of the smoothed curve points? That'd be absolutely helpful

Comment: No, but you can look at the source code in `CPTScatterPlot` to see how Core Plot does it.